# Drupal 6 Ajax module: altering form after submission

Tags: ajax, drupal-6

I am using Ajax module in Drupal 6 to ajaxify my simple contact form. It works fine, the form is ajax-submitted and validation errors are displayed correctly, but I can't figure out a way to alter my form after successful submission. Namely, I want to remove most of my input fields and replace them with a "Thank you for your request" message. I assume this should be somehow achieved with hook_ajax_validate_pass, but I have no idea how to use it... Any help appreciated.